# NATIVESCRIPT - Core(JS) - Want to hide TabView on Login page

Tags: javascript, nativescript, tabview

I'm working an a Nativescript App, using Javascript. In Angular, there is this Page-Routing, to bring user to a login page without TabView. How to realize this on a Javascript based Apps?
Or is there any chance, to hide the TabView on pages?

Would be nice, to get an answer. I couldn't find any helpful informations on the web at the moment.

Best regards,
Tobias

Comment: Show your research efforts

Comment: The author of the article [Implementing a Login for NativeScript Apps with Tab-based Navigation](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/implementing-a-login-for-nativescript-apps-with-tab-based-navigation) in his comments points to repository https://github.com/ADjenkov/login-tabs which show one technic of implementing login with tabview.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I found that article (Implementing a Login for NativeScript Apps with Tab-based Navigation) as well. I'm a bit new in Nativescript programming, so it is hard for me, to convert that Angular project into plain JS. Would be great to have that tutorial for JS.

Answer (score 0):

`page-router-outlet` is nothing but a `Frame` in Core application. If you use right frame, you can still avoid the TabView in your Login Page. The structure will be something like

-- App Root (Frame)

----- Login Page

----- TabView

-------- Frame for each tab view item, similar to using page-router-outlet in Angular.

If you prefer to just hide the TabBar, you may do this

**XML**

```
<Page loaded="pageLoaded" class="page" xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd">

    <ActionBar title="Home" class="action-bar">
    </ActionBar>

    <TabView id="tabView" androidTabsPosition="bottom" selectedIndex="1">
        <TabView.items>
            <TabViewItem title="Tab 1">
                <TabViewItem.view>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label class="m-5 h3" text="Label in Tab 1" />
                        <Button text="Show" class="btn btn-primary" tap="onShowButtonTap"></Button>
                        <Button text="Hide" class="btn btn-secondary" tap="onHideButtonTap"></Button>
                    </StackLayout>
                </TabViewItem.view>
            </TabViewItem>
            <TabViewItem title="Tab 2">
                <TabViewItem.view>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label class="m-5 h3" text="Label in Tab 2" />
                        <Button text="Show" class="btn btn-primary" tap="onShowButtonTap"></Button>
                        <Button text="Hide" class="btn btn-secondary" tap="onHideButtonTap"></Button>
                    </StackLayout>
                </TabViewItem.view>
            </TabViewItem>
        </TabView.items>
    </TabView>

</Page>
```

**JS**

```
var frameModule = require("tns-core-modules/ui/frame");
var HomeViewModel = require("./home-view-model");

var homeViewModel = new HomeViewModel();

function pageLoaded(args) {
  var page = args.object;
  page.bindingContext = homeViewModel;
}

function onShowButtonTap(args) {
  var tabView = args.object.page.getViewById("tabView");
  if (tabView.ios) {
    tabView.viewController.tabBar.hidden = false;
  } else if (tabView.android) {
    tabView._tabLayout.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);
  }
}

function onHideButtonTap(args) {
  var tabView = args.object.page.getViewById("tabView");
  if (tabView.ios) {
    tabView.viewController.tabBar.hidden = true;
  } else if (tabView.android) {
    tabView._tabLayout.setVisibility(android.view.View.GONE);
  }
}

exports.pageLoaded = pageLoaded;
exports.onShowButtonTap = onShowButtonTap;
exports.onHideButtonTap = onHideButtonTap;
```

[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=9dlMNH&v=3)